# PHP cUrl not posting

Tags: php, curl, post

I want to send json data using cURL in php, but the problem is that cURL is not posting any data.

NOTICE: cURL is properly installed and configured.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
//The JSON data.
$jsonData = '{
    "recipient":{
    "id":"'.$sender.'"
},
"message":{
    "text":"'.$message_to_reply.'"
}
}';


$jsonDataEncoded = $jsonData;

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array($jsonDataEncoded));

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_exec($ch);
```

The json Data is working fine but the cURL post is not posting anything and also not giving any type of warnings/notice or error.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't post anything? Also, json is rarely URL encoded, are you sure you want that? Finally, that `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` use is not adviced, just remove it. And consider following redirects (common after POSTs).

Comment: @DanielStenberg because i'm using ngrok and there is no stats regarding posting. Also i removed the urlencode() but it is still not working.

Comment: Not logged in the receiving end is not necessarily the same thing as "not posting anything" though...

Comment: @DanielStenberg ok buddy, but do you know why it's not working?

Comment: Can you perform this cURL action to your site and give us var_dump of $_POST and $_GET?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i can see, you do 3 mistakes

1: don't do `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");`, the correct way to tell curl that you want a POST request is `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

2: when you give CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS an array, its actually converted to a `multipart/form-data` encoding, which is not what you want (you want to transfer a json)

3: your $sender and $message_to_reply  seem to be just inserted in to the json raw. what happens if your $message_to_reply  contains an `"` or `'` ? it will invalidate the json. consider encoding it properly, for example using json_encode, like

```
$jsonData = array (
        'recipient' => array (
                'id' => $sender 
        ),
        'message' => array (
                'text' => $messaage_to_reply 
        ) 
);
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode ( $jsonData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

but, provided that $sender and $message_to_reply is already properly json encoded, the only reason your original code doesn't work, as far as i can see, is that you give CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS an array, thus, all that's needed to fix it would be to remove "array" from that line, like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$jsonDataEncoded);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(json_decode($jsonDataEncoded)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

You probably don't want to pass all data to one key.
Output of `print_r(array($jsonDataEncoded))`

```
Array ( [0] => { "recipient":{ "id":"me" }, "message":{ "text":"hello" } } )
```

Output of `print_r(json_decode(array($jsonDataEncoded)))`

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [recipient] => stdClass Object ( [id] => me ) [message] => stdClass Object ( [text] => hello ) ) )
```

Comment: that will not post a JSON, that will post the data with multipart/form-data encoding (when you give curl_setopt an array, its automatically converted to multipart/form-data)

Comment: If he wants to pass the json as a string, the code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well after all the try, Here is the answer:

```
$jsonData = '{
"recipient":{
    "id":"'.$sender.'"
},
"message":{
    "text":"'.$message_to_reply.'"
}
}';

$jsonDataEncoded = $jsonData;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
//Here i removed the array//

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// By default in PHP7 CURL_SSL_VERIFYPEER, is true. You have to make it false//

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```